# R url.exists returns True for a URL which doesn't exists

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm under a corporate proxy and I'm trying to automatically download some files from a ftp address. When I try to download without the url.exists, the download.file function "downloads" an empty file, that's why I'm using it.

Here is an example

```
library(RCurl)
opts <- list(
  proxy         = "http://xxxxx.xxxx:8080",
  proxyport     = 8080
)

url.exists("ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/Bovespa-Opcoes/NEG_OPCOES_20200113.gz", .opts=opts)
```

The output is:

```
[1] TRUE
```

This address doesn't exists yet, so it should return false.

When I turn off the proxy parameters, I got FALSE (and I was expecting this) for any address that I try. Let's see google, for example:

```
opts <- list(
  proxy         = "http://xxxxx.xxxx:8080",
  proxyport     = 8080
)

url.exists('http://www.google.com.br')
```

Returns:

```
[1] FALSE
```

Why the first code is returning True? Only found cases where an URL exists and returns False, not the opposite.

Thanks

Comment: What if you pass `.header = TRUE`? What header is returned for the value that returns TRUE? One potential problem is that `url.exists` is meant to test an HTTP response but you seem to be using it for an FTP response. It's very hard to guess what might be going on since we can't reproduce the result without access to the proxy server.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me see if I get it. I've inserted in url.exists the parameter .header and still responds me True for a url which doesn't exist. For second case, still the same thing.